# How to Configure using STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider with roleSessionName and roleArn for AWS SDK for Java 2.x?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Currently for AWS SDK for Java 1.x im using below code.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:aws-context.xml")
public class AmazonS3Config {
 @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
 public AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client(@Value("${aws.s3.roleSessionName}") String roleSessionName, 
 @Value("${aws.s3.roleArn}") String role) {
 AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
 builder.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(new 
 STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(role, roleSessionName).build());
 return (AmazonS3Client)builder.build();
   }
```

How to do the same for AWS SDK for Java 2.x?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The equivalent of `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` in SDK V2 is `StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider`.

So the equivalent S3Client initialisation in V2 would look like below

```
public S3Client s3Client(@Value("${aws.s3.roleSessionName}") String roleSessionName,  
        @Value("${aws.s3.roleArn}") String role) {

 return S3Client
       .builder()
       .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
       .credentialsProvider(StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider
               .builder()
               .refreshRequest(() -> AssumeRoleRequest
                       .builder()
                       .roleArn(role)
                       .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                       .build())
               .build())
       .build();
```

The maven/gradle dependency group and the package names have changed to `software.amazon.awssdk` in V2. Ensure to include the dependencies for `S3` and `STS`. [Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/LaunchChangelog.md) is the change log and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/migration-guide/what-is-java-migration.html) is the migration guide.

Answer (score 2):

TO learn how to return a set of temporary security credentials using the V2 **StsClient**, look at this example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/sts/src/main/java/com/example/sts/AssumeRole.java

You can find the corresponding POM file here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/sts

All Java V2 Service code examples are located here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2

Java V2 DEV Guide is here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html